# Crystal Reports SDK error

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, nuget-package

I am trying to run a report with the Crystal Reports SDK I got from Nuget. 
The error is:

> InnerException = {"Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.C...

I can see the `CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer` namespace, but not the CommLayer part???

I have the following dlls:

- CrystalDesicions.CrystalReports.Engine 13.0.2000.0
- CrystalDesicions.Shared                13.0.2000.0

Am I missing any others?
Do I need to have Crystal Reports installed on the machine? If so which version?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the full SDK from the Crystal Reports (SAP) [website](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824),

I had to install it on my machine. Just pick the newest one (Service Pack 16) if you're starting out.

I'm not 100% sure it needs all of these, but these are the dlls I referenced to get mine to work.

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back. Small mushroom cloud! Thanks again!